# How does this self outputting C program works?

Tags: c, quine

here is the smallest code that output itself. But can't grasp how this works. can somebody explain?

```
main(a){printf(a,34,a="main(a){printf(a,34,a=%c%s%c,34);}",34);}
```

Comment: What exactly you didn't get?

Comment: Btw, is this valid C syntax? Which standard, by the way?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda If it ever were, it's no longer standards-compliant due to `main`'s prototype.

Comment: @Medinoc: True enough.

Comment: Did you try reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing) ?

Comment: I would also smell undefined behavior.

Comment: This also depends on the order `printf` arguments are evaluated, which is not standardized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet it won't work on a 64-bit platform unless its model is ILP64 (64-bit `int`s), because it relies on `int` being big enough to contain a `char*`.

It declares a variable `a` that contains a copy of the code minus the string itself, and uses printf()'s formatting codes to output both the code and the string. Do you need more details?

Comment: +1, but it works for most PC, `int` is big enough "in practice", for fun.

Comment: It's a (dangerous) shortcut for declaring the `a` local variable: Here it's declared as a parameter of main, with its type implicitly `int`. Declaring it as a true `char*` inside the function body would have been the right thing to do, but would have made the quine longer.

Answer (score 1):

These codes called as [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) codes.The computer languages supports this features till a fixed point.
As per wikipedia

> a fixed point (sometimes shortened to fixpoint, also known as an
>   invariant point) of a function is an element of the function's domain
>   that is mapped to itself by the function

means means  `f(f(...f(c)...)) = fn(c) = c` where c is some constant 
for example

```
 f(x) = x^2 - 3 x + 4,
then 2 is a fixed point of f, because f(2) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main(a){printf(a,34,a="main(a){printf(a,34,a=%c%s%c,34);}",34);}
```

can be rewritten to

```
main(a) {
    a = "main(a){printf(a,34,a=%c%s%c,34);}";
    printf(a, 34, a, 34);
}
```

These two versions are not equivalent, but you could use the second version to understand what is going on in the first version.